# Deploy Spring Boot jar to Azure, and make Azure restart

Tags: java, spring, azure, jenkins

I build a Spring Boot jar on Jenkins, and upload through FTP to Azure, but since the app is still running, and I get error below. What is the recommended way to handle this on azure? I assume I somehow should shut the server down before uploading the jar, and start it again after upload.

```
..........
FTP: Connecting from host [ip-172-20-20-20]
FTP: Connecting with configuration [Back-End-Azure-FTP] ...
FTP: Disconnecting configuration [Back-End-Azure-FTP] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not write file. Server message: [550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over FTP' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of implementing this can be using spring actuator. They are documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-endpoints) . They have a lot of handy instrumentation API and shutdown is one of the ways. You can drop in a simple POM dependency and that should do it (also enable shutdown in application yaml)

Before you run your FTP part , you will have to execute a post call through cURL to stop it and then deploy the new version package.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Sprint Actuator, added it and tested out. The shutdown works, but dangerous having that public available, then everyone could shut down my servers.